# Array_multisort fails if date is equal

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, yii, array-multisort

I am using `yii` framework and using `CArrayDataProvider` because my data provider contains 3 tables .But if I am using `Sort` in this.

```
$sort = new CSort;
        $sort->defaultOrder = 'created DESC';
        $dataProvidermain=new CArrayDataProvider($data, array(
            'id'=>'user',
            'sort' => $sort,
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>20,
            ),
        ));
```

It is throwing the error

> Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in
>   /var/www/goalsurf/framework/web/CArrayDataProvider.php on line 151

After debugging, i come to know that it is throwing this error when the date of 2 or more elements are equal. I have three entities with the same date.`2016-02-06 10:10:51`. If i change the date of 2 records, it is working . Trying to solve this from past 2 days. Searched google but no solution.

Help me please.

**Update**
This is the array format

```
[68] => Tasks Object
        (
            [taskmodel] => 1
            [quickacent] => 15
            [dailygoal] => 
            [weeklygoal] => 
            [dailygoal2] => 
            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 563
                    [guid] => 650c7572-3fae-4f9a-a476-8de6a21c329e
                    [user_id] => 44
                    [deli_id] => 0
                    [branch_id] => 0
                    [main_goal_id] => 0
                    [title] => Buy Babycon Dress
                    [thumb_ext] => 
                    [description] => 
                    [ecv] => 
                    [isSpam] => 0
                    [displayorder] => 0
                    [created] => 2016-02-06 10:10:52
                    [modified] => 2016-02-06 10:10:52
                )
         )
)
```

**update 2**

My `$data` variable is

```
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Goals', array('criteria' => $criteria,'pagination'=>false));

   $dataProvider2=new CActiveDataProvider('Tasks', array('criteria' => $criteria2,'pagination'=>false));

   $dataProvider3=new CActiveDataProvider('TasksDaily', array('criteria' => $criteria2,'pagination'=>false));
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($dataProvider2->getData()); die;
    $data=array_merge($dataProvider->getData(),$dataProvider2->getData(),$dataProvider3->getData());
```

Comment: `$sort` calls `$sort`, which makes this `$sort` recursive so that is why it throws that error. maybe figure out some other names for `$sort` ?

Comment: i changed the variable name from `$sort` to `$sortvariable` but no change

Comment: can you post your data in array format in question

Comment: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1032177/94d444a00696a9b9ccb5d2296506afdc

Comment: what is the format of $data. Can you please show the query of $data

Comment: please check . i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try that: `$sort->defaultOrder = 'created DESC, id ASC';`